# Charting the data from database using one column only

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to create chart that read the Extra_Process column in my database..It only have two value. "Rush Order" and "Normal Order"

i have this code...

```
chart1.Series["Order Process"].Points.Clear();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Extra_Process, sum(Extra_Process) qty FROM sketchit.monitoring GROUP BY Extra_Process; ", dc.con);
        MySqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            dc.con.Open();
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {

                this.chart1.Series["Order Process"].Points.AddXY(myreader.GetString("Extra_Process"), myreader.GetInt32("qty"));
                chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;



            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        dc.con.Close();
```

I want to know how many rush order and normal order in my column but  it doesn't show any result. I don't know what to do.

[here's the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvdJv.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. Query and get the Count value of both RushOrder and NormalOrder.
2. Once you get the both count pass it to the following function to generate the `PieChart`

[image: Sample Image]

```
 private void btnChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Make your Query , Get Count Value for RushOrder and NormalOrder
     //Check for Null Value
     //Pass the Count to the DrawPieChart() function


     //Sample Chart Generation 
     int nRushOrderCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtRushOrder.Text);
     int nNormalOrderCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtNormalOrder.Text);
     DrawPieChart(nRushOrderCount, nNormalOrderCount);
  }

  private void DrawPieChart(int nRushOrder, int nNormalOrder)
  {
     //reset your chart series and legends
     chart1.Series.Clear();
     chart1.Legends.Clear();

     //Add a new Legend(if needed) and do some formating
     chart1.Legends.Add("MyLegend");
     chart1.Legends[0].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
     chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
     chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
     chart1.Legends[0].Title = "Order Details";
     chart1.Legends[0].BorderColor = Color.Black;

     //Add a new chart-series
     string seriesname = "MySeriesName";
     chart1.Series.Add(seriesname);
     //set the chart-type to "Pie"
     chart1.Series[seriesname].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

     //Add some datapoints so the series. in this case you can pass the values to this method
     chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("Rush Order", nRushOrder);
     chart1.Series[seriesname].Points.AddXY("Normal Order", nNormalOrder);

     chart1.Series[seriesname].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
  }
```

Comment: is there shortcut way to do it? i mean I'm gonna put it in my form_loard..

Comment: You can Call this method in the `Form_load`. Since you are just passing int value to it wouldn't be much difference in loading the Chart in UI Thread. Else you can use `Background` Thread to load chart alone.